# wordpress comments

Tags: php, wordpress, комментарии

Всем привет.
Необходимо на странице "добавить отзыв" разместить форму, через которую комментарий будет размещен на странице "отзывы", никак не могу разобраться, как это реализовать, т.е на одной странице комментарии добавляются без проблем, а вот редиректить их на другую никак не получается.
Если коротко - на одной странице должна быть только форма комментирования, на другой - вывод комментариев.
Кто сталкивался с подобными задачами - напишите пожалуйста, как вы их решали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте на целевой странице функцию `get_comments()` для вывода комментариев, указывая id страницы, к которой они привязаны (той, на которой вы выводите форму комментирования). Например, если id равен 15:

```
$comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo('Автор: ' . $comment->comment_author); //автор
    echo('Текст комментария: ' . $comment->comment_content); //текст комментария
}
```

Вот подробная [документация](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) по функции.